# refresh page doesn't refresh scroller javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I refresh the page, the javascripts (scrollers) do not refresh as they stay in the same position that they started. What code do I need to implement into each javascript that will allow the scroller to refresh at the same time the page refreshes?

I saw this:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

but this didn't work.

JS

Here is my JS:

```
$(function () {  // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        var dir = this.id == "right" ? '+=' : '-=';
        $(".outerwrapper").stop(false,true).animate({ scrollLeft: dir + '251' }, 1000);
    });

});
```

And I have this at the top:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Try `window.location.href=window.location.href`

Comment: I'm placing these inside and outside the javascripts and nothing is working so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following just before reloading the page.

```
$('body').scrollTop(0);
```

EDIT: The above solution is scrolling vertically while I think you want to scroll horizontally.

I've looked at the code you added, try the following:

```
$(".outerwrapper").scrollLeft(0)...
```

Comment: this didn't work, scroll up to see the added JS scripts to see if I could of placed it inside the file wrong

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

this will scroll to the top left corner of the window.